# Develop a static library in Visual C++ for efficient numerical computation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, metaprogramming, static-libraries, expression-templates

I've the following problem:
I need to devlop a static library (*.lib) in visual C++ for efficient numerical computation.
I've started defining a new template class "Matrix" and I've read that best efficiency may be achieved with expression templates.
But I've also read (and I've experienced it) that I can't enclose expression templates in a static library because you need to explicitly istantiate all the combinations.

So - for example - if I want to do in a new project:

```
Matrix<int> M_A, M_B, M_C, M_D;

M_C = M_A + M_B + 2 * M_D;
M_C = 2 * M_B;
M_C = M_A + 2 * M_B;
```

importing my *.lib file, I've to istantiate in my static libraries 3 different combination to permit the equalities M_C = Expression.

Is there a method or a "best practice" to simplify the explixit istantiation in the static library? Or, there is an alternative to expression templates allowing the same efficiency without export problems? 
For clarification, I need to preserve the possibility of compact notation like: M_C = M_A + M_B + 2 * M_D;

Thank you.

Ps.
I add more details to better explain:

If I create my static library I'm able to use it in an extern project but I've to export
all the template specialization.
        template class __declspec(dllexport) Matrix;
        template class __declspec(dllexport) Matrix;

and so on...

The problem is that I've to do the same with all possible expression to permit the equalities (M_A = M_B + M_C, for example).
I've to export something like this:
           template class LibraryNameSpace::Matrix const & __thiscall LibraryNameSpace::Matrix::operator=,int>(class LibraryNameSpace::myExpression,int>);

Without enclosing all the code in a lib file, there is no problem for me: I'm able to use my library without problems.  The issue is related to enclose expression templates in static libraries. I need to do that to mask the code and don't make final users able to read it.

Comment: I know there are a lot of free libraries on numerical computing and expression templates but I want to learn by doing one on my own. I need to best understand the method to develop more difficult things. Thank you.

Comment: Since nobody has actually answered your question so far: make your library a header library, then let the user instantiate the correct templates with whatever type he wants to do so.

Comment: Are you sure you need a static library? From the Eigen site: " If you just want to use Eigen, you can use the header files right away. There is no binary library to link to, and no configured header file. Eigen is a pure template library defined in the headers. "

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm editing the question to better explain. @H2CO3: may you please add more details?

Answer (score 0):

This is something you probably should not develop yourself from scratch unless you do it for educational purposes.

Have a look at [Blitz++](http://blitz.sourceforge.net). According to its manual, it compiles to a static library.

Comment: Thank you. I've had a look to it but it doesn't solve my problem. I'm able to compile my lib file but I'm not able to use it in a simple way. I'm editing my question to better explain.

Answer (score 0):

Before developing your own ET linear algebra library, have you considered using existing ones?

You have a choice between (in no particular order): [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), [Blaze](https://code.google.com/p/blaze-lib/), [uBlas](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) and [blitz++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blitz/).

They are all libraries using Expression Templates to get rid of temporaries for mixed matrix/vector operations and some of them (Blaze and Eigen) go a step further and specialize templates for specific matrix/vector operations (smart Expression Templates). All of the mentioned libraries are developed by groups (some scientific) of people and have been debugged and tested, and documented in open scientific publications, and using Wikis, etc.

I would suggest to consider if re-inveinting the wheel fits here, because of the complexity of the topic. If you want efficienty, the easiest answer is to adapt an existing efficient library to your needs.

Comment: Is this an answer? There's plenty of work on interpolation, numerical optimization, solution of partial differential equations all around but nevertheless people is wishing to have their own implementations and asking questions. Why? Fetishism? Model building? Curiosity? Will to know/understand? Maybe the need to have a customized, light, and modifiable implementation? Who knows...Your counter-question is just subverting the nature of progress: the irrational push to knowledge :-)

Comment: @JackOLantern: I didn't mean it as a negative comment, but as advice to think about. I wasted a lot of time in rolling my own hacked code and thought that I am learning this way. The best way I found to learn stuff is to dig through, use and extend existing excellent code written by much better programmers than myself. Then, if I find something missing, I will know how to extend the code properly. Reading about ET and doing stuff yourself, will most likely end up in a library, without the "efficient" adjective. If efficiency is what is needed (stated in the question clearly), use what's there.